# MYSQL LEFT JOIN log Table to retrieve last log filtered is very slow

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables:

- 'PartNumber' with unique ID 'Part Number' and several fields like 'Description' and 'Workflow Status' ID :
  `'Part Number' 'Description' WorkflowStatus'` 
  `ZU0000        RES 1K 1%     4`               
  `ZU0001        RES 2K 1%     2`               
  `ZU0002        CAP 10nF 10V  3`               
  `...`
- 'WorkFlowStatus' with 'ID' and 'Workflows Status' being the text associated to 'PartNumber.Workflow Status':
    `'ID'   'Workflows Status'`
    `1      New`
    `2      Verified`
    `3      Approved`
    `4      Modified`
    `...`
- 'LogWorkflow' which corresponds to a logger of all the actions made on 'PartNumber' but also several other types, identified by 'Type' and 'Reference' i.e. for a 'PartNumber', 'Type'='PN' and 'Reference' = 'PartNumber'.'Part Number' (ZUxxx):
  `'ID'   'Reference'  'Type'     'Recipient' 'Date'     'PrevStatus'  'NextStatus'`
  `1      'ZU0000'      PN         Robert      2023.12.01   2           4 #` 
  `2      'ZU0001'      PN         John        2023.10.02   NULL        1`
  `3      'ZU0001'      PN         Librarian1  2023.10.04   1           2 #`
  `4      'CR06031K00'  MPN        Mitch       2023.11.04   2           3`
  `5      'ZU0002'      PN         Robert      2023.12.01   NULL        1`
  `6      'QFN100-200'  Footprint  Mitch       2024.01.08   NULL        1`
  `7      'ZU0002'      PN         Librarian1  2024.01.10   1           2`
  `8      'ZU0002'      PN         Librarian2  2024.01.10   2           3 #`
  `9      'QFN100-200'  Footprint  Mitch       2024.01.11   NULL        1`

I want to link the 'PartNumber' table with 'WorkFlowStatus' and 'LogWorkflow' having the last logged ID in the 'LogWorkflow' table for the PN Type.
These ID are pointed by the 3 # for the 3 Part Number listed

I made this request but this is very very slow. Is there a way to optimize it ?

```sql
SELECT 
 `PartNumber`.`Part Number`, `PartNumber`.`Description`,
 `WorkflowStatus`.`Workflow Status`,
 LW.`N°`, LW.`Recipient`
FROM `PartNumber`
LEFT JOIN `WorkflowStatus` ON `PartNumber`.`WorkflowStatus`=`WorkflowStatus`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT LW1.`Type`, LW1.`Reference`, LW1.`N°`, LW1.`Recipient` FROM `LogWorkflow` LW1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(`N°`) AS`MAXNUM` FROM`LogWorkflow` WHERE `Type`='PN' GROUP BY `Reference`)
 AS LW2 ON LW1.`N°` = LW2.`MAXNUM`)
LW ON `PartNumber`.`Part Number` =  LW.`Reference`
```

The Sub query in the left join is very fast but when associated to the part number table with left join it's very slow

I checked several topics in stackoverflow to write this SQL query which actually works but slowly

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3. Also provide precise MySQL version. PS. Why LEFT joining and not INNER?

Comment: See answers to the duplicate question with several different solutions to the row with the max value problem and test which one works the best for you.

Comment: LEFT joining 'cos some PN created before a code revision don't have any log record ( new parts) and I want to have them in the list (log N° and Recipient will be null).\ Server : MariaDB 5.5.68, protocole 10